# equivalent definition of positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: reference-request, optimization, positive-semidefinite

A matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $y^T M y \geq 0$ for all possible $y$. 
We can also show that $M \succeq 0$ if and only if $[\bar{y}^T,1 ]M[\bar{y}^T,1]^T \geq 0$ for all possible $\bar{y}$. That is we fix the last element of $y$ to be 1. This can be proved by the continuity of $ y \rightarrow y^T M y$.

My question is: is this well-known? If so, is there a reference for this?

Comment: It is not a definition.

Comment: whatever you can call it a classification.  Just want to find a reference to this trick.

Comment: I don't think it has a name.

Comment: Ok is this trick well-known? Do you know a reference or I just need to do the argument myself before using this trick?

Comment: I think it would fall into the 'fairly clear in context' category. I don't have a reference.